# Operate on a list of Maybe values

Tags: haskell, functor, option-type

I can multiply a list per 2:

```
(* 2) <$> [1, 2, 3]
```

But I want multiply the elements which are Just:

```
(* 2) <$> [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
```

Error:

> ```
> * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Maybe a)
>   (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
> * When checking the inferred type
>     it :: forall a. (Num (Maybe a), Num a) => [Maybe a] Prelude Data.List
> ```

Another try:

```
fmap (* 2) [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
```

Error:

> ```
> * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Maybe a)
>   (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
> * When checking the inferred type
>     it :: forall a. (Num (Maybe a), Num a) => [Maybe a]
> ```

I have tried more things: map2, fmap2, map (*2) map, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to map twice: once to get inside the list, second time to get inside the maybe. The operator `<$>` only maps once, and you can't use the same operator twice, so you have to add a call to `fmap`:

```
fmap (* 2) <$> [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
```

Comment: Sure you can, the syntax is `((* 2) <$>) <$> [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]`. Only do this if you like being deliberately obtuse.

Answer (score 10):

A straightforward solution is adding another `fmap` to get through the `Maybe` layer:

```
GHCi> fmap (* 2) <$> [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
[Just 2,Nothing,Just 6]
```

Alternatively, that can be expressed using [`Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html), which allows handling the two functor layers as one:

```
GHCi> import Data.Functor.Compose
GHCi> (* 2) <$> Compose [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
Compose [Just 2,Nothing,Just 6]
GHCi> getCompose $ (* 2) <$> Compose [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
[Just 2,Nothing,Just 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compose 2 `fmap` functions:

```
(fmap . fmap) (*2) [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3]
```

The first will be the fmap of the list, the second is the fmap of the maybe.